# How to store random numbers in muntiple items without repeating the last one javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have already tried most similar answers but they didn't work or are too old.

i'm trying to generate random dates, so i already have the following:

```
  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
  }

  const dataMonth = randomIntFromInterval(1, 12)
  const dataDay = randomIntFromInterval(1, 30)
  const data-Year = randomIntFromInterval(15, 22)
```

if i try to put more than 1 of them in react like this:

```
    return (
<h1> {dataMonth}/{dataDay}/{data-Year} </h1>
<h1> {dataMonth}/{dataDay}/{data-Year} </h1>
  )
```

it will generate equal number for both. How can i do it to generate unique for each that i want to?

Comment: Where is the declare the randomIntFromInterval ? I believe if it is instanciated inside each component the random generator (that is not really random) will have the bias of the false random and thus generating the same numbers.
If you can declare the function as a global or a inside the parent component this results should be different.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call the function rather.

```
 return (
   <h1> {randomIntFromInterval(1, 12)}/{randomIntFromInterval(1, 30)}/{randomIntFromInterval(15, 22)} </h1>
   <h1> {randomIntFromInterval(1, 12)}/{randomIntFromInterval(1, 30)}/{randomIntFromInterval(15, 22)} </h1>
 )
```